# Conditional "the_content" filter wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a filter added for "the_content" in functions.php

```
add_filter ('the_content', 'testFilter');
function testFilter($content) {
  if(is_single()) {
    $content.="Append content";
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Now in my content-post.php. I have the following line :

```
the_content(__('Test;', 'tag') );
```

How do I exclude the testFilter from being applied on the content-post.php  page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `remove_filter` function above your function `the_content(__('Test;','tag'))`.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'testFilter',11 );
the_content(__('Test;', 'tag') );
```

Comment: I see that you have set the third param to 11 which it the priority...
any specific reason for 11?

Comment: It is for priority. Bydefault it was set to 10. So I add priority to 11.

Comment: Thanks.. i'll just add this for my reference
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter

Comment: The third argument for `add_action` and `remove_action` is, as you've already identified, the priority. It's important to note however that you can't remove a filter with a different priority than it was added with.